# SQL Server Report Builder : Concatenate data type "date" and "time"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am working with SQL Server Report Builder 2008 R2.

I have a dataset that contains `DateEntry (date, null)` and `TimeStampAuto (time(7), null)` columns. I am trying to write an expression for concatenating those two values, so I can put it under `DATETIME` column on the report table. I tried the following but it does not work. It displays "#Error."

```
=First(Fields!DateEntry.Value, "Report1) & " " & First(Fields!TimeStampAuto.Value, "Report1)
```

When I just put the first part of the expression shown above, the report displays the date with some random time value (5/1/2015 12:00:00 AM). However, I did not put any time value in `DateEntry`. I only put the dates.

When I put the second part of the expression shown above, the report displays correct time that the data has.

I don't know why I can not concatenate those two.

Answer (score 0):

The system type of the `DateEntry.Value` will be a DateTime value which is the readon that your report is showing `5/1/2015 12:00 AM` even though it is only a date field in the database.

You need to format the date to only include the day,month and year to remove the included default time of `12:00 am`

you will probably need to check for `null` values in both your date and time fields.  you will also need to format the time filed to exclude any default date information.

Comment: I could format DateEntry.Value and it shows only dates 5/1/2015. And I tried to concatenate the time value, it did not work. I could concatenate another Date value or string value though. It seems that I can not concatenate DATA TYPE time. Do you have any idea why?? There's no null values.

Comment: Got it. I should have used values from Fields.                                     Fields!DateEntry.Value + Fields!TimeStampAuto.Value